# Play audio file during ongoing voice call so that caller can hear it

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an answering machine.

When there is an incoming call in my device I'll pick it up and start an audio file enabling speaker so that the microphone can take the speaker voice and the caller can hear it.

The application is working. This is what I implemented. But the problem is when I receive the call and start the audio play, the speaker is set on but the microphone doesn't pick up anything from the speaker though it can pick sounds from other source. Hence caller can't here the audio.

Anyone have an insight of this problem? I mean why won't the microphone pick the voice from the speaker but at the same time pick sounds from other sources?

Comment: Isn't there anyone to answer the question. I need it badly!!!

Comment: Android api doesn't allow to play audio during call like caller tune.

Comment: I don't want it to play as caller tune. I want to play it in music player so that the microphone can grab the sound coming from the loudspeaker. But the problem is the microphone doesn't capture the sound from loud speaker though its capturing sounds from all other sources at the same time.

Comment: yeah..you have to on the speaker programmatically..so that when the music play, it could capture the music. It also obvious that it would capture some other sound too.

Comment: I think I was not able to clarify the situation completely. Allow me to do it again. I did set on the speaker programatically. But its picking up all sounds from every sound source except the sound from the speaker.

Comment: hi did you got the solution? me too need this. kindly help me.

Comment: @azizul fahim:Did u get anything fruitful.. If yes just share it along

Comment: its not possible because of echo cancellation. when you talk with someone in speaker mode, the other party will hear himself again and again if echo cancellation isn't in effect. Thats why it is important to cancel all echo, which is the main reason of our problem.

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @azizulhakim did u find solution for this problem??

Comment: @Jeeva it is not possible. The device will filter out the sound that is coming out from device speaker. Otherwise you will always hear your own voice when you call someone and the other person put you on speaker. But it can be done if you modify the kernel may be. But that is not scalable solution.